# xmltask (ANT) :: replace withtext not working for null value of xml element

Tags: xml, ant, xmltask

I am trying to replace xml field value using xmltask ( ANT script ) . But it is not replacing the value if the xml element is empty.

for example :

```
   <Mydoc>
      <doc>
      <docname>abc.txt</docname>
      <doclocation>xyz</doclocation>
      </doc>
      <doc>
      <docname>mmm.txt</docname>
      <doclocation></doclocation>
      </doc>
    </Mydoc>

in the above example i want to update the "doclocation" element if "docname" element is "mmm.txt"
```

Script used to achieve it.

```
        <xmltask dest="sample.xml">
         <fileset file="sample.xml"/>

            <replace 
            path="/Mydoc/doc[docname="mmm.txt"]/doclocation/text()"
            withText="newURL"/>

          </xmltask>
```

the above piece of code is not working if 'doclocation' element has null/no value.

what needs to be done here to handle the null values and replace it with the new value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the doclocation element entirely for all cases, using a CDATA section, e.g.:

```
     <property name="newURL" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com"/>
     <xmltask source="sample.xml" dest="result.xml">
        <replace path="/Mydoc/doc[docname='mmm.txt']/doclocation">
           <![CDATA[ <doclocation>${newURL}</doclocation> ]]>
        </replace>
     </xmltask>
```

Comment: Is there any way to replace the text , if the text does not exists ??

Comment: This code should work for <doclocation/> or <doclocation></doclocation>. Is that what you're asking ?

Comment: yes , it should be able to insert text in the element <doclocation/> or <doclocation></doclocation> without replacing the whole element with Cdata tag , is it possible ?

Comment: My solution replaces the whole element, and I trust you have tried it. Can you explain under which circumstances it would be a problem to replace the whole element as opposed to 'just' the content ?